# Which word can replace the word "right" in this context?

Tags: word-choice

Which clearer word can replace the word "right" in this context?

> "Perpendicular lines: Lines that are at **right** angles (90°) to each
>   other."

Comment: The term *right angles* is a technical term with a precise and unambiguous meaning in this context. You can't get better clarity by replacing the word *right* in your given sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The only equivalent replacement would be what is already given in parentheses. In other words, perpendicular lines are lines that intersect each other at 90°. You can also say perpendicular lines are lines that are square to each other, but I don't know if the replacement makes it any clearer.